# Surface/Volume-Ratio of an $\epsilon$-extension of a compact subset $S \subset \mathbb R^n$

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For a non-empty, compact set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, the [$\epsilon$-extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#In_a_metric_measure_space) of $S$, $S_\epsilon$, is defined to be the set
$$
S_\epsilon = \cup_{a \in A} B_{\epsilon}(a),
$$
where $B_\epsilon(a)$ denotes the closed ball centered at $a$ with radius $\epsilon$.

Can we say something about the monotonicity of the function 
$$
f(x) = \frac{\lambda(\partial S_x)}{\mu(S_x)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}, \, x \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}, \tag 1 
$$
i.e, the ratio of the [Minkowski content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Steiner_formula)
$$
\lambda(\partial S)=\liminf_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{(\mu(S_\epsilon)-\mu(S))}{\epsilon}\tag 2
$$
and the Lebesgue measure $\mu(S_x)$? In particular, is $f(x)$ monotonically decreasing with $x$, and thus maximized at $f(0)$ such that the following inequality holds:
$$
\frac{\lambda(\partial S_x)}{\mu(S_x)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}} \leq \frac{\lambda(\partial S)}{\mu(S)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}, \, \forall x \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}? \tag 3
$$

Furthermore, if this is not true, does the assumption of $S$ being *connected* or even *simply connected* help to establish the above inequality $(3)$?

Answer (score 2):

**The function $f(x)$ need not be decreasing or even continuous.** Let $S$ be the union of three segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
$$
S=([0,0.1]\times\{ 0\})\cup(\{0\}\times[0,1])\cup (\{0.1\}\times[0,1]).
$$ 
This is a thin letter U with the base of length $0.1$ and height $1$. If $x=0.05+\epsilon$, then the boundary of the neighborhood $S_x$ has length close to $2$ because the space between $\{0\}\times[0,1]$ and $\{0.1\}\times[0,1]$ is covered by the set $S_x$, but if $x<0.05$ then there is a gap in the set $S_x$ between $\{0\}\times[0,1]$ and  $\{1\}\times[0,1]$ so the boundary of the set $S_x$ has length close to $4$. The function $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0.05$ and jumps from a smaller value to a larger one.